# Rebooting the Android device through instrumentation testing and continuing the test after reboot

Tags: java, android, restart, android-instrumentation

I am planing to create a test that needs to be checked across several reboots, I am aware that when the device is rebooting the test disconnects from the device.
My question is, can I manipulate the instrumentation testing to be able to work across reboots without wrapping the instrumentation with an outer layer?